# Adjusting the format of PL/SQL output

Tags: oracle, plsql, sqlplus

```
FOR rec_c IN cus_cur LOOP
 DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(TO_CHAR(rec_c.CNO)||'  '||rec_c.person.name||'   '||rec_c.person.address.street||'   '||TO_CHAR(rec_c.person.address.zip));
FOR i IN 1..rec_c.person.phones.count loop
DBMS_OUTPUT.put_LINE(rec_c.person.phones(i));
END LOOP;
END LOOP;
```

The graph below is the output for the code:

[image]

How can I manage a output like the picture below?

[image]

Comment: You cannot be bothered to copy the text from an  image to a post for people to spend their free time answering your question. You are yanking my chain

Comment: Use `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT()` (rather that `DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE()`) and if you couple that with `RPAD( value, width, ' ' )` then you should get your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like:

```
FOR rec_c IN cus_cur LOOP
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( RPAD( rec_c.CNO,                    6, ' ' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( RPAD( rec_c.person.name,           11, ' ' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( RPAD( rec_c.person.address.street, 14, ' ' ) );
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT( RPAD( rec_c.person.address.zip,     7, ' ' ) );

  IF rec_c.person.phones IS NOT EMPTY THEN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_c.person.phones(1));
    FOR i IN 2..rec_c.person.phones.count LOOP
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( RPAD( ' ', 38, ' ' ) );
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(rec_c.person.phones(i));
    END LOOP;
  ELSE
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE( NULL );
  END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Answer (score 0):

before executing above block in sqlplus just set the linesize to 200 or more, eg:

```
set linesize 200;
set serveroutput on;
Begin
  -- Your code
End;
/
```